# Destroy clone prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem. In a scene I have a list and when I click on it shows me with some clones prefab the contents of the database. The point is that once generated, no matter how much I select another item from the list, the prefabs do not update me and show the contents of the first selection. I've tried to destroy them. But the most I've managed to do is destroy the original prefab and don't believe me anymore. How can I fix this?

```
public Transform contentParent;
public List<TablePlayerTransctData> playersTransct;
public GameObject playerTransactItemPrefab;
private Models.Club _club;
public TextMeshProUGUI memberUuid;


public void Start()
{
    GetTablePlayerTransactRequest();
}


private void GetTablePlayerTransactRequest()
{
    _club = TablesManager.Instance.club;

    new LogEventRequest().SetEventKey("Transactions")
        .SetEventAttribute("clubId", _club.id)
        .SetEventAttribute("playerId", memberUuid.text)
        .Send(GetTablePlayerTransactResponse);
}


private void HandleResults()
{
    var cont = 0f;

    Vector3 posicion = new Vector3();

    foreach (TablePlayerTransctData data in playersTransct)
    {
        GameObject item = Instantiate(playerTransactItemPrefab, contentParent);
        PlayerTransact playerTableTransact = item.GetComponent<PlayerTransact>();

        if (cont == 0)
        {
            posicion = playerTableTransact.transform.position;
        }
        else
        {
            posicion.Set(posicion.x, (posicion.y) - 0.5f, posicion.z);
            playerTableTransact.transform.position = posicion;
        }

        playerTableTransact.Setup(data);

        cont++;
    }
}

private void GetTablePlayerTransactResponse(LogEventResponse response)
{
    if (response.HasErrors)
    {
        return;
    }

    GSData scriptData = response.ScriptData;
    var list = scriptData.GetGSDataList("list");
    playersTransct = new List<TablePlayerTransctData>();

    foreach (GSData entry in list)
    {
        TablePlayerTransctData data = new TablePlayerTransctData()
        {
            chips = GSUtil.GetInt(entry, "chips"),
            date = GSUtil.GetDouble(entry, "date"),
        };

        playersTransct.Add(data);
    }

    HandleResults();
}

public class TablePlayerTransctData
{
    public int chips;
    public double date;
}
```

I think these prefabs should be reset or removed just before they are re-created. But I don't know how to do this or maybe there's another, more correct way to do it.

Edit:
I changed Start to Update and magically works almost as it should. I don't understand what this miracle is like. Since with starting every time you enter you should cool off on your own. Now all that remains is to remove the leftover prefabs which is what I don't finish doing properly.

Comment: you are only showing how you generate the prefabs, all the select and update stuff where the problem seems to be is not exposed in the question

Comment: he added all the code

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that `unityscript` is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used by early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! You code is clearly in `c#`

Comment: Ok derHugo, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before instantiating the new items you could destroy them all like e.g.

```
// General hint: Make this of the correct type
// - Makes sure that the referenced prefab actually HAS that component
// - Gets rid of some GetComponent calls later since Instantiate already
//   returns the same type as the given prefab has
public PlayerTransact playerTransactItemPrefab;

foreach(Transform child in contentParent)
{
    Destroy(child.gameObject);
}

foreach (var data in playersTransct)
{
    PlayerTransact item = Instantiate(playerTransactItemPrefab, contentParent);
    ...
}
```

---

Alternatively you could of course only create the amount of objects you need and destroy others and instead of destroying and recreating all of them **reuse** those that already exists like e.g.

```
// cache the counts
var childCount = contentParent.childCount;
var dataCount = playersTransct.Count;
// we want to iterate the count that is greater
var count = Mathf.Max(childCount, dataCount);

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if (i < dataCount)
    {
        // there is data for this index
        var data = playersTransct[i];

        // so we need a child for it
        PlayerTransact playerTableTransact;

        if (i < childCount)
        {
            // We are still in the range of existing childs -> Re-use a child that already exists   
            playerTableTransact = contentParent.GetChild(i).GetComponent<PlayerTransact>();
            posicion = playerTableTransact.transform.position;
        }
        else // i < dataCount && i >= childCount
        {
            // There is still data but no childs left -> create a new one now
            playerTableTransact = Instantiate(playerTransactItemPrefab, contentParent);

            if (i == 0)
            {
                posicion = playerTableTransact.transform.position;
            }
            else
            {
                posicion -= Vector3.up * 0.5f;
                playerTableTransact.transform.position = posicion;
            }
        }

        playerTableTransact.Setup(data);
    }
    else // i < childCount && i >= dataCount
    {
        // There are more childs than data -> destroy the unneeded childs
        Destroy(contentParent.GetChild(i).gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried the two codes, but I'm eliminated by the father prefab and it leaves me the invisible clones. I've been told by a colleague, who could make a second list where to save the created objects and remove them from the list before generating new ones. But I don't know very well what you mean.

Comment: In the end, the first solution has helped me. Thx